# GPO for Multiple Home Page tabs in IE 7

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer-7, homepage

The organization in question currently has a GPO set which was primarily setup in IE6 days. This GPO enforced a non-changeable homepage of the company portal page. Since IE7 and tabbed browsing have been introduced, they would like to have the company portal opened as the home page and a second tabbed homepage set to a search engine (Google / Bing - Whatever).

I cannot see a way to do this with a Group Policy setting. It appears GPO is not tab / IE7 aware. Or is that just my version/system.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Given that there's a search box in the toolbar isn't it superfluous to also forcibly open a tab with a search engine page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Group Policy Preferences. I just double-checked here and there are options to set multiple tabs to open in either IE7 or IE8.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731892(WS.10).aspx

To use GPP, you will need to have the client-side extensions installed on the clients.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Internet Explorer Administration Kit and Group Policy addin for IE7.

Here's a blurb from an IE developer http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/02/21/536353.aspx

And here's where you can download the Admin Kit: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/bb381619.aspx

Comment: Thats useful thanks, but even with that, I can't find out the GPO addin for IE7. The download appears to just be the IEAK which wants to talk me through creating a package, which is not needed as all machines already have it.

Comment: Here's the ADM file to enable all the fancy IE 7 GPO settings
http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=11AB3E81-6462-4FDA-8EE5-FCB8264C44B1&displaylang=en

Comment: Having now put the gpo addin for the IE7 - I unfortunately still can't see an option to allow multiple urls / homepages

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue with IE8. The GPO doesn't allow me to set more than one homepage.

The easy solution right now is to implement it straight in the user profile and disable home page change by GPO, in condition that they all use the base mandatory profile.

The IEAK kit is a great ideas if you want to upgrade you terminals to IE8. You can also use it to create a config file that will be push to you client, put could be a pain if you have many client...

Answer (score 0):

A quick search finds this as an option if you are not adverse to setting things up as a logon script for your users.

User config/windows settings/scripts/logon

The code:

// JavaScript Document

var navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000;

var oIE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");

oIE.Navigate2("http://www.homepage1.com");

oIE.Navigate2("http://www.homepage2.com", navOpenInBackgroundTab);

oIE.Visible = true;